# Maximum of $xy^3z^7$ in the plane $x+y+z=1$

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

A friend gave me this problem and on having seen that I could not solve it in the first instance helped me with the hint of using the AM-GM inequality.

PROBLEM.- To maximize the product $xy^3z^7$ with non-negative real numbers such that $x+y+z =1$

Comment: Do you want to maximize $xy^4z^5$ or $xy^3z^7$?

Comment: @CC0607: Sorry, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$1 = x + y + z = x + \frac{1}{3}y + \frac{1}{3}y + \frac{1}{3}y +  \frac{1}{7}z + \cdots + \frac{1}{7}z \geq 11\sqrt[11]{x\left(\frac{1}{3}y\right)^3 \left(\frac{1}{7}z\right)^7}$$

Comment: And what is the point $P(x,y,z)$ which gives the solution?

Comment: @ Do you know the equality-holding condition for AM-GM inequality?